# Object variable or With block variable not set while running the VBA codes

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I took over someone's vba codes which previously run perfectly until one day, it suddenly stop to this line "sSenderName = (OutItems(i).Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress)". It's been running smoothly so not sure exactly what happened now that it suddent encountered the runtime-error 91.

```
Sub save_email_attachments()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim OutDefaultFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim OutItems As Outlook.Items
Dim OutAttch As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSenderName As String
Dim sFilename As String
Dim sFileextenstion As String
Dim CountOfEmails As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim findText As String
Dim replaceText As String
Dim origString As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim conversion As Workbook
Dim depot As String



Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application

If OutApp Is Nothing Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 10)
End If

 

Dim OutputFolder As String
OutputFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\xxx\xxx\"

Dim OutputFolder1 As String
OutputFolder1 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\xxx\aaa\"

 

    If Not OutApp Is Nothing Then
    Set OutNamespace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set OutDefaultFolder = OutNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


    Set OutItems = OutDefaultFolder.Items
    If Not OutItems Is Nothing Then CountOfEmails = OutItems.Count
     

    If CountOfEmails <> 0 Then
    For i = CountOfEmails To 1 Step -1
    If TypeName(OutItems(i)) = "MailItem" Then
       If OutItems(i).SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
       sSenderName = (OutItems(i).Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress)
                Else
                    sSenderName = (OutItems(i).SenderEmailAddress)
                End If
       End If
```

Didn't want to ruin the codes so i have not changed anything yet. Hope to get some help!

Comment: runtime error 91 arises when an object variable is not set. Did you debug the code trying to figure out whether OutItems(i) or OutItems(i).Sender or OutItems(i).Sender.GetExchangeUser is not set?

Comment: OutItems was already declared as String and from my understanding, .Sender.Getexchangeuser will just return an email add.

Comment: `OutItems`, `Sender` and `GetExchangeUser` are all objects, none of them are strings.

Comment: `.Sender` can be `Nothing` or `.Sender.GetExchangeUser` can return `Nothing` so you should check them before using return value. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239858/outlook-mailitem-sender-is-null-to-fetch-from-email-address

Comment: but it's showing me an email address when i move the cursor to sSenderName so it's not null or nothing. but when i try to move it to next line of codes, the runtime error 91 shows up.

Comment: Okay. Got it now. This article helped a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895718/outlook-vba-error-when-sender-is-group-email
Now understood that each objects mentioned need to be declared.